# Get classes of hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show/hide columns of a table using jQuery. When the page is reloaded, the selection of the tables showed should be the same as before. Therefore every column of the table has its own class. 
How can I get the classes of the hidden elements?

```html
<thead>
  <th class="apple" style="display:none"> Apple</th>
  <th class="orange"> Orange</th>
  <th class="banana"> Banana</th>
  <th class="ananas" style="display:none"> Ananas</th>
</thead>
```

The following selection does not work..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide_apple").click(function(){ 
    //change visibility for apple-column
       
    //this doesn't work:
    var myClasses = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
      alert(myList[0].style.visibility);
      for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++) {
     if (myClasses[i].style.visibility === 'hidden') {
       alert(myClasses[i].className);
          //save class name in cookie..
        }
      }
  }
}
```

The name of the class I save in a cookie. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

You're using `visibility` instead of `display`:

```
if (myClasses[i].style.visibility === 'hidden')
```

Change that to:

```
if (myClasses[i].style.display === 'none') {
```

Further more, since you're already using jQuery, your whole loop can change to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('th:hidden').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('th:hidden').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="apple" style="display:none"> Apple</th>
    <th class="orange"> Orange</th>
    <th class="banana"> Banana</th>
    <th class="ananas" style="display:none"> Ananas</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

This loop will run over all the hidden `th`s (you can of course change the selector to be more specific if you need it to) and alert the class.

Comment: Fixed it for you :). You were using the first parameter in the `each` function, which is actually the index **not** the element :)

Comment: I blame jQuery, the first parameter should have been the element, gets me everytime!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I do it with the forloop, it never executes the if-condition. also the jQuery solution doesn't give an alert..